What are OpROM policies?
Question
Within my UEFI's GUI, I see two options:



Launch PXE OpROM Policy




Launch Storage OpROM Policy



...of which both can be set to either "Do not launch" or "UEFI only".
The description of each preference is, verbatim, as undermentioned:

Select UEFI only to run those that support UEFI option ROM only. Select Do not launch to not execute both legacy and UEFI option ROM.

The option labels (like "UEFI only") themselves are trivial enough to understand, but I don't know what the more verbose description means at all. I dare say that, as a native speaker of English, it's rather difficult to parse whatsoever.
Consequently, can someone explain what these OpROM preferences are, and how the two aforementioned options for each preference alter them?
Environment
I'm using an ASRock X670E Taichi motherboard.
(Lack of) Duplicates

https://superuser.com/search?q=what+is+oprom+policy returns 4 results, of which none appear relevant.
Google hasn't returned any useful results for the query of "OpROM" policy either – it merely displays the occasional thread where someone has accidentally correlated enabling the preference to something irrelevant.


I would presume opROM Policy stands for option ROM policy since you are choosing between two policy options. Microsoft supports this assumption.

Do you have a specific option ROM you are confused by?, my previous comment, contained and invalid link.

@Ramhound, not confused per se, just surprised that there was no information online. However, "option ROM policy" does yield results (like your referenced documentation). I wasn't aware of what option ROMs were either, so didn't consider that it would be a contraction of that. Thank you.

OpROM policies is a somewhat glorified designation for whether Option ROMs should be executed by the BIOS/UEFI or not.
In a nutshell: Option ROMs are pieces of software that support certain types of hardware, mostly for adding boot support to the BIOS/UEFI. They are essentially drivers that enable the BIOS/UEFI to access hardware that it would otherwise be unable to access.
For example, RAID add-on cards have Option ROMs (typically in a flash chip on the card) so that the BIOS/UEFI can boot from a RAID drive or array. Motherboards with chipsets that support RAID have the RAID Option ROM included directly in the system BIOS/UEFI. The same goes for Network cards in order to support PXE network boot.
If you don't need to boot from network, you can set Launch PXE OpROM Policy to Do not launch. The same with Launch Storage OpROM Policy: If you use a AHCI (SATA) or NVMe drive, you can set it to Do not launch as most newer motherboards' BIOS/UEFI supports these types of drives directly, without the need of an Option ROM.
If your platform supports CSM, you usually have an additional setting, Legacy only, which would be required if you use a Legacy (non-UEFI) operating system to support Legacy-style booting.

Thank you! That explained it well. Is there any disadvantage to enabling these options, like a boot time increase or security vulnerability? I can't see why I'd leave them as "do not launch" except if I want to be confused when I next attach some hardware that doesn't work.

Yes and yes. However, the impact is small and the security scenario is pretty unlikely. As mentioned in my answer: If you don't need the functionality that they provide on a regular basis, you could turn them off.
As for attaching hardware, a rule of thumb: If you don't need to open your PC to attach the hardware, OpROMs are most likely not involved. Things like USB devices do not require OpROMs.

Yeah, I meant PCIe (or NVMe) HW. I don't use SATA or IDE anymore.
